# Running 32-bit sun-jdk in 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, java, jdk, 32-bit

I need to run 32bit sun-jdk on my 64bit ubuntu.  I downloaded JDK and when run I get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/java/32/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1724)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraries(NativeLibLoader.java:38)
    at sun.awt.DebugHelper.<clinit>(DebugHelper.java:29)
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:566)
    at com.mucommander.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:466)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mucommander.text.Translator.get(Translator.java:258)
    at com.mucommander.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:612)
```

I installed libXtst6 and libext6:i386 to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: This setup was needed for my previous workplace for Juniper VPN and I ended up using chrooted x86 environment

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem with missing libxtst.so. I solved it by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
sudo apt-get install libxi6
```

The complete command is:

```
sudo apt-get install libxi6 libxtst6 libxrender1
```

Comment: Please note that it's advisable to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing or updating software from the command-line. `sudo apt-get update` fetches updated information about what packages are available in what versions from where.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing [ia32-libs [image: Install ia32-libs]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ia32-libs)? I am a java-android developer, and I need to install this when I make a fresh installation of android-sdk (which is 32 bit) in my 64 bit Ubuntu.
I tried this with Ubuntu 12.04 and now on 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to install three libs. Each time I run `rcu` after a lib install, I saw another lib missing error in my system. So below libs and order worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install libXext6:i386 
sudo apt-get install libXtst6:i386
sudo apt-get install libXi6:i386
```

Comment: Thank you, this one `sudo apt-get install libXi6:i386` work for me on ubuntu 14.04 after fresh installation. i spent a hall day figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have run into your downloaded binary depending on different libraries than those you have installed.

If you just need *a* Java installation, and not a *Sun* Java installation, do a `sudo apt-get openjdk-6-jdk` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must:

1)`make`

```
rm ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64
ln -s /usr/lib/jni ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64
```

2) Install this:

```
sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-java
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

Comment: if you have any error with state of  Installation Manager , you can locate installRegistry.xml file and update X version <?installRegistry version='0.0.X'?>